# JQuery for checkbox is not working properly for particular server

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am having a same code which works properly in a testing server but it's not working in the development environment server. Is that any configuration files are needed for doing this JQuery for running it in a server?

Comment: No jquery is platform independent and doesn't need any configuration. It runs in all platforms and all browsers. Make sure you have set the correct permissions for the folders in the server

Comment: what do you mean by jQuery for checkbox? It is not a jQuery problem. Check the path of your reference file. Please see the console for any errors.

Comment: can you provide any links to that site

Comment: @ddw147 its an internal web site so i cant give you link sorry

Comment: check for server configuration for allowing static content , check web console for jquery loaded or not

Comment: @ddw147 may i know how to check that my server is loading static content

Comment: @user3141191 first check in your browser console that j query file is loaded successfully or not , if you are using IIS server then you might be check in MIME types for .js File

Comment: @ddw147 I am working in JSP application

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the issue and found like the issue with the backend data from the database.
we are taking unique value to point to the javascript id, but in DB also it should be unique value. Unfortunately some one mocked duplicated value and the javascript got confused and created a problem. Thanks for the support. @ddw147,manishankar and shaunakde.